# remove border from text inputs

Tags: css, forms

I have followed instructions verbatim using border:none and background:transparent, but a border still shows in the my text areas.  I am using a background image to customize the look, but can not seem to remove the border.

website in question 
http://www.officeyoganyc.com/

**markup**

```
  <div class="fieldHolder">
  <div class="attributeinput1"><input type=text name=email value="email" size="16"> 
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">addFieldToCheck("email","Email");</script></div> 
  </div>
```

**css**

```
  .fieldHolder
{
    width: 137x;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(http://www.officeyoganyc.com/themes/zen/zen/images/textarea.png) no-repeat;
    margin-left: 209px;
        margin-top: 162px;
}



  .attributeinput1
{

    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    height: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 170px;

}
```

Comment: add border: 0; to your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This selector:

```
.attributeinput1 {
```

Only styles the `<div>`. You want the `<input />` *inside* the `<div>`:

```
.attributeinput1 input {
```

---

By the way, the `input` tag is self-closing:

```
<input ... />
```

Your site might look funky in IE if you omit the `/>`, as it might be treated as the beginning of a block element.

---

Also, one more thing (just a nuance in HTML), the `language=` attribute in the `<script>` tag is depreciated (i.e. unsupported and old). You can safely omit:

```
language="Javascript"
```

in your `<script>` tags.

---

If you use Google Chrome or Firefox, there is a really useful tool you can use. In Firefox, it's called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). In Google Chrome, it's called something like **Inspector**.

They both allow you to "inspect" the webpage's layout and see what CSS properties affect what elements.

Here's what I mean. Look at the right-hand-side:

[image]

I used this to confirm that your CSS wasn't being applied properly. To activate it, right click on any part of a webpage and click "**Inspect**".

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly right. The border:none property isn't being applied at all to the input element. I assume the OP is fairly new to HTML/CSS, and I suggest learning how to use the webkit developer tools in Chrome or Safari (or Firebug in Firefox) for examining pages.

Comment: Yep, that would be quite useful (that's what I did :P).

Comment: Thanks I  like firebug better than chrome's inspect.  This explanation really helped.

Comment: this got rid of the initial border but now there is a yellow border on active in chrome.  that can not be undone though so thanks.

Comment: It can be, but it's a standard Chrome feature. I think it would confuse users.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many attributes for your background and border definitions.

This should work.

.attributeinput1 input {
    border:0;
    background:none;
}

If not then try

.attributeinput1 input {
    border:0!important;
    background:none!important;
}